# Is making a "hanging indent" (CTRL+T) like Microsoft Word possible with html5?

Tags: html, css

How can I make a "hanging indent" `(CTRL+T)` like Microsoft Word with html5?

```
.center-indent{
    /*some styles here*/   
}
```

Is something like this possible and at the same time be responsive?. Or may I have to indent every line in order to make it similar.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `padding` and `text-indent` for this:

```css
p {
  padding-left: 5%;
  text-indent: -5%;
}

.fixed-px {
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-indent: -20px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .fixed-px {
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-indent: -15px;
  }
}

/* more media queries here if necessary */
```

```html
<p>
  Pharetra eros mi eros accumsan dui. Pellentesque ipsum iaculis. Mi neque in nonummy venenatis vestibulum. Class egestas adipiscing nisl tellus quam ut in amet. Nostra nunc leo lorem eget ipsum elit eget metus nam sed pede. Nam nibh risus sit dui nullam.
  Consequat luctus tempus.
</p>

<p>
  Pede tellus eu mattis morbi donec. Natoque class leo. Ac lacus vestibulum ac odio ac. Risus lorem mauris. Proin enim tortor at erat dui. Aliquam magna condimentum. Orci donec morbi. Id justo at malesuada erat nulla urna quam eu nec elit commodo mi voluptatum
  gravida ante bibendum justo. Eleifend nec eget. Id massa quis eu vitae elit. Bibendum interdum semper. Donec libero duis. Phasellus malesuada adipiscing qui et eu. Justo egestas erat auctor sagittis sed nonummy amet dolor et in id. Ut blandit justo.
  Donec fringilla cursus enim velit ullamcorper.
</p>

<p class="fixed-px">
  Pharetra eros mi eros accumsan dui. Pellentesque ipsum iaculis. Mi neque in nonummy venenatis vestibulum. Class egestas adipiscing nisl tellus quam ut in amet. Nostra nunc leo lorem eget ipsum elit eget metus nam sed pede. Nam nibh risus sit dui nullam.
  Consequat luctus tempus.
</p>

<p class="fixed-px">
  Pede tellus eu mattis morbi donec. Natoque class leo. Ac lacus vestibulum ac odio ac. Risus lorem mauris. Proin enim tortor at erat dui. Aliquam magna condimentum. Orci donec morbi. Id justo at malesuada erat nulla urna quam eu nec elit commodo mi voluptatum
  gravida ante bibendum justo. Eleifend nec eget. Id massa quis eu vitae elit. Bibendum interdum semper. Donec libero duis. Phasellus malesuada adipiscing qui et eu. Justo egestas erat auctor sagittis sed nonummy amet dolor et in id. Ut blandit justo.
  Donec fringilla cursus enim velit ullamcorper.
</p>
```

If you use `%` values, it will be responsive - or you can use `media queries` and a fixed `px` value for each break point.